# Channel Tabs in Teams through Graph-API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

is there a possibility to get Name/Id/Url of tabs in Teams-Channel?
If no, are there Plans to provide it through Graph API? ETA?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a timeline as I am not on that team, but I do know the team are actively working on an API for accessing tabs.  I expect you will hear some news during Ignite.

Answer (score 1):

The api was just released! checkout the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channels_tabs_add)
here is a sample 
`POST /beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/tabs`

```
{
  "name": "My Contoso Tab",
  "teamsAppId": "06805b9e-77e3-4b93-ac81-525eb87513b8",
  "configuration": {
    "entityId": "2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "contentUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/tabView",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "removeUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/uninstallTab"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the Parameter "teamsAppId" is? I always get an Error Response.I want to add an "Website" tab trought graph. Example response: "App id 06805b9e-77e3-4b93-ac81-525eb87513b8 needs to be installed to the team 06805b9e-77e3-4b93-ac81-525eb87513b8 and be in an unblocked state to install/update a tab"

Comment: nevermind, with a GET call u can read all existing apps. Website would be: "teamsAppId": "com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web",