# Team Apps using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am looking at automating Group creation using Graph API in Teams. I can successfully do that by using following API

```
const result = await client.api('/groups').post(group);
```

What I am looking for is creating a Tab in that Group and then adding an Organisational app (Internal App) into that tab.

Here is the link for creating tabs in teams but could not see anything on adding app into that tab

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-1.0

Is it possible ? and if so, where can i see APIs and relevant documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, to add a Tab, you need to have the content of that tab configured and waiting. There are two ways to do this:

1. point to a website directly - this would be equivalent of using the "Website" option in the UI to add a tab, and then inserting the address of the website. This is kind of what the Graph endpoint sample you linked to is doing, but you need to use the payload specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#website-tabs). See the answer over here for more info: [Channel Tabs in Teams through Graph-API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001079/channel-tabs-in-teams-through-graph-api)
2. Use an existing registered App in Teams that has a "Tab" functionality. The same link I gave above has options for doing this, like Planner, or Word, or whatever. You would be able to do the same thing for your *own* custom app, but then the app needs to be built, and installed into the tenant app catalog (i.e. the internal company "store"), or the Teams "App Store". Read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs)

Comment: For me option 1 worked really well. I had to develop background application to dynamic Teams and adding tabs to it. Thanks